# Change class with jQuery/JS in specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html-table

For this case, I work with table. (Follow up architecture) 
By default "tr.classified" is display none.

I want to add a button who display "tr.classified" when needed.

I'm not a web developer.

I started with this;

```
<script>
$( "buttonchange" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).switchClass( "tr.classified", "tr.classified2");
});
</script>

<div class="buttonchange">Display Archives</button>
```

Not working at all :(

Can you give a look at this ?

Comment: Please provide the corresponding `css` classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switching between two different classes jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043235/switching-between-two-different-classes-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `toggleClass` in jquery

```
$( "#buttonchange" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass("classified classified2");
});
```

[**TOGGLECLASS**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: i copy # from you, but you copy all my code after 4 min

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$( "#buttonchange" ).click(function() {     //put '#' here for 'id' selector
   $( this ).toggleClass("classified classified2");  // use 'toggleClass' as shown here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many example across the web of the usage of `jQuery`'s `toggleClass` function, I suggest you look it up.

In the meantime, here's how how to solve your problem:

1. Add a `toggle-master` class to the rows you want to toggle.
2. toggle the `classified` class on these rows when clicking the toggle button using the following code:

   $("buttonchange").click(function(){
       $(".toggle-master").toggleClass("classified");
   });

You don't need a `classified2` class if `classified` is the class responsible for hiding the elements.

Don't forget to add the code inside the `$(document).ready(function(){/*add here*/});` function and to include `jQuery` on your page.

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/swLkg4q1/).

Answer (score 0):

well you just need to add a event handler for the button and show or hide your table there like this,

**HTML Code:**

```
<button class="clik">Display/hide Table</button>
<table id="codexpl">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Columna</th>
    <th>Relative</th>
    <th>Isso</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Is</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>is</td>
    <td>not equals</td>
    <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>the</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>real</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Coloumn</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
//hide the table by default
$('#codexpl').hide();

$(".clik" ).on('click',function() {
   $('#codexpl').toggle();
});
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/eboLopwc/1/

Happy Coding :)